# Video editor desktop app for Windows .NET or python

Tags: python, .net, opencv, video-editing

I want to make a desktop app for video editing. It will be a Windows based app. My question is should I use python or .Net, because main part is working with video and audio. I know that .NET's wpf is great framework for making desktop apps (I have experience in it) with its xaml for creating GUI and all tools which .NET provides, but OpenCV in python is great tool for video editing and I do not have any experience in making desktop apps in python or any GUI based apps. Can .NET offer me some libraries for video editing that could match OpenCV ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .NET to build your solution and use FFMPEG libraries which are available for integration with .net code it supports lot of features for video/audio editing. It also supports CLI commands so that you can run the long processes in the background as separate process and it doesn't need to block resources in your main desktop application.

https://github.com/mysteryx93/FFmpeg.NET
https://www.ffmpeg.org

Comment: Could I use it for commercial projects ?